# Removing URLs in a text file

Tags: string, text, replace

I have a text file structured like this, where there are strings of text (containing spaces), and a line break between each message:

message
message
https://...
message
...

Sometimes the messages are URLs, is there a tool/webapp which can remove the whole line if it is a URL?

I tried using find & replace to remove them, but it can only do so for the "https://" part, the unique parts after that will be left behind

Comment: you need to specify the programming language or tools that you are working with

Answer (score 0):

you can use command line tool like `grep` it is mostly pre installed in linux or mac if you are using one

and use a command
 `grep -vE '\bhttps?:\/\/\S+' input.txt | sed '/^\s*$/d' > output.txt`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using windows.